# PostgreSQL count distinct per 6 months grouped by month

Tags: postgresql

Using PostgreSQL, I need to count how many distinct clients are active each month where active means they’ve posted a job within a 6 month period... and display that by month.  So for example, 2018-10 has 300 clients that had posted a role between 2018-10 and 6 months previous.  2018-09 has 310 clients that had posted a job between 2018-09 and 6 months previous and so on.

I know how to do it for one month but confused when building a monthly history.

Comment: Please [take a look at this question](https://dba.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2976/help-me-write-this-query-in-sql)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something near

```
SELECT t1.date, COUNT(DISTINCT t2.client_id)
FROM table t1, table t2
WHERE t2.date BETWEEN DATEADD(month, t1.date, -6) AND t1.date
GROUP BY t1.date
```

but dates must be rounded to month.

Comment: Thank yiu, I can’t get it to run though as it’s too slow!

Comment: *it’s too slow* Any query which solves your task on current structure MUST be slow - to check the time difference between two records is less than 6 months you MUST add/substract 6 month to/from at least one of them. It cause to fullscan by one of the table copies at least. The only way to increase performance I see is to add 2 columns to your table structure (or create separate table with these columns linked to your table as 1:1) and store year/month values for `table.date` and `table.date - 6 month` in them. These columns must be indexed, of course. It must improve your task solution.